# Importing from one sub-module into another sub-module

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I'm struggling with python's imports.

I have my repository for my python projects in which I have a collection of more or less independent programmes and tools. There are a few sub-folders which contain the single scripts and programmes; some can be used as helper routines for others scripts as well. Assume that my folder structure looks like:

```
root
   __init__.py
   prog1.py
   prog2.py
   imaging
        __init__.py
        filter1.py
        detect_edges.py
   data_tools
        __init__.py
        floating_mean.py
        unify_data_sources.py
        prog3.py
```

Now assume that I want to use `prog3.py` directly but need call `filter1.py`. How can I import it into `prog3.py`?

The only way I managed to import it was giving adding to the path which needs modification of `sys.path`.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../imaging/")
from filter1 import filter1
```

As I know the relative way the modules are located, is there another way similar to what is described in python's module import guide ([here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages-in-multiple-directories) and [here](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html#absolute-vs-relative-import)) without changing sys.path?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to call filter1.py for importing shared functions or classes, I would use relative imports as described in the python tutorial.

**filter1.py**

```
def some_shared_func1():
    pass

def some_shared_func2(): 
    pass
```

**prog3.py**

```
from ..imaging.filter1 import some_shared_func1, some_shared_func2
# filter1 is reached from prog3 by go two levels up then one level down to `imaging` folder.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Do something with some_shared_func1
    # Do something with some_shared_func2
    pass
```

I would then run prog3.py with `-m` argument to resolve relative imports but without extension:

```
python -m root.data_tools.prog3
```

Current directory must be the one containing `root` (or be defined into PYTHONPATH variable).

I don't modify `sys.path`.

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes and no. The usual way that I call my programmes and scripts is from within Spyder. This solves mostly my problem for the times when I run it from normal command line. Yet Spyder allows to set the current dir which I can set to e.g. root. Yet then it fails to find functions imaging when I execute a file from data_tools.